# Flutter : while snackbar api wrapping, "Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions" error happen

Tags: flutter

I'm writing flutter snackbar wrapper for easy use but I got "Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions" error at "Text(str)" and "A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'int' in a const constructor" error at "Duration(milliseconds: duration_in_ms)".
There is no "const" define but couldn't fix the problem.
Can anyone help on this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Utils{
  static showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String msg, int duration_in_ms) {
    String str = msg;
    var snackBar = const SnackBar(
      content: Text(str),
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: duration_in_ms),
    );
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just get rid of `const` in front of `SnackBar `?

Comment: ok, got it...with your comment, I could realize there is "const" keyword..Thank you ^^

Comment: I'm glad it helped ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the "Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions" error, you need to ensure that the values you pass as arguments are constant expressions. For example, if you are creating a Text widget and passing a string stored in a variable called str, you cannot use Text(str) directly because str is not a constant expression. Instead, you can use a constant string directly or use the const keyword to create a constant expression, like const Text('Your Text Here').

Regarding the "A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'int' in a const constructor" error, it indicates that you are trying to assign a null value to an int parameter within a const constructor. The const constructor requires all its parameters to have non-null constant values. Make sure that you are not assigning null to any int parameters within the constructor. You are assigning duration_in_ms to the milliseconds . You should makes sure the duration_in_ms value is not equal to null .